# Xpages - Open a dialog for a few seconds and close it again

Tags: dialog, xpages

I want to open a dialog box that should be visible for a few seconds (2 seconds maybe) and then closes automatically.
Can anybody give me a hint how to solve that? Is there any timer function I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the client side function `setTimeout()` to achieve this. Insert following CSJS code to your button which opens the dialog box:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        ... client action to hide dialog or XSP.partialRefreshGet/Post ...
    }, 2 * 1000);
```

The first parameter is the function which shall be executed at timeout and second parameter is the number of milliseconds for timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I've you're also looking for something like this, check this out:
https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/a-control-for-dojox.widget.toaster

This uses the following component and works with dojo:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/widget/Toaster

Answer (score 0):

From UX point it's not a good idea to use popup. Try to use standard Dojo component Toaster.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/widget/Toaster.html#dojox-widget-toaster
https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/AA9764E10494D4E585257A7000425672

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Solution from Knut Hermann, but you should insert a clearTimeout() function to stop open and closing the dialog box

```
<xp:scriptBlock
id="scriptBlockRefresh">
<xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
            var myVar = setTimeout(function() {
                ... client action to hide dialog or XSP.partialRefreshGet/Post ...
            }, 2 * 1000)

            clearTimeout(myVar);
        ]]>
</xp:this.value>
```

Comment: The function from setTimeout()'s first parameter get's executed only once http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp . It might be useful to call clearTimeout() when user closes the dialog box though.